# Ввод чисел с клавиатуры внутри цикла в C#

Tags: c#

У меня возникла проблема: я должен ввести числа с клавиатуры внутри цикла for.
Мой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Untitled_31
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string value;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
            {
                value = Convert.ToString(Console.Read());
                Console.WriteLine($"i = {i}");
            }

            Console.Write("Press any key to exit the program...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

По идеи, я должен вводить числа с клавиатуры на каждой итерации цикла, но вместо этого я получаю следующее:

```
9
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
5
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
7
i = 6
i = 7
Press any key to exit the program...
```

Я не понимаю, где я ошибся. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Замените Console.Read на Console.ReadLine

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё заработало! Но почему не работал вместе с метод Read?

Comment: Console.Read()
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.8
Читает следующий символ из стандартного входного потока.
Возвращаемый тип - int, код символа

Answer (score 2):

Метод Read читает один символ и возвращает управление вам в программу. На входе один символ, если вы хотите число, то это будет "цифра" - число от 0 до 9, а вот больше вы не введёте.

Метод ReadLine читает "строку" - символы, пока вы не нажмёте Enter.

При этом поскольку вы о таких особенностях стандартной библиотеки не знали, не приходило в голову ввести число больше 10, вводить достаточно медленно - у вас и возникали подозрения, что "работает как-то не так". Но это как-то не так пустило вас по ложному следу.

Попробуйте мысленно отдебажить вашу программу, а также [вот эти](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5515c215-6701-4a05-ba0a-9cd63ef206df/difference-between-readreadline-and-readkey-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral) и понять разницу:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i;
        while ((i = Console.Read()) != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", i, (char)i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

и такую:

```
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Your input is {0}.", s);
```

Ссылки по теме:

- [Console.Read](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netcore-2.1)
- [Console.ReadLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-2.1)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5515c215-6701-4a05-ba0a-9cd63ef206df/difference-between-readreadline-and-readkey-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral
- [Difference between Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6825943/5752652)